# create a default number of db connections at startup golang

Tags: go, go-xorm

I want some idle db connections to always there on application startup.

I can only see `MaxIdleConns` and `MaxOpenConns` in Golang.
I don't see any `setMinIdle` func.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: "I don't see any setMinIdle func" because there is none.

Comment: Yes. Is there no way to achieve this?

Comment: No, I doubt it (there might be hacks), but a minimum number of idle connections sounds like just wasting resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target the main part of your question, you could iterate a decided number of times and make a parallel request to your database before marking your app as started. (For instance for k8s readiness probe).

In general, when selecting a configuration for the connection pool configuration, there are few things to consider:

1. By default, no limit of open connections is present, thus if some bug occurs or an unexpected high influx of incoming requests, it may be impactful for DB. That's why one should set `SetMaxOpenConns`.
2. If connections will live forever, it's also not the very best situation. As they take memory and DB resources. So - set `SetMaxIdleConns`, remember, it's default value is **2**.

The common practice for a production-grade setup is to set the DB connection pool to have a limit on `MaxOpenConns`, which depends on expected requests per second, number of workers and configuration of the database. As for `MaxIdleConns` — it should be set to a fraction of MaxOpenConns, consider set your expectation on what's the dispersion of simultaneous requests. Like 25 % or 50% of MaxOpenConns.